# Correct way to store/retrieve data in an android app using facebook api

Tags: php, android, mysql, facebook

I'm implementing facebook authentication/retrieve user info, on my android app. I already have a database with a user table. They can log in with username/pass.

Okay, now I want them to be able to connect to my app using facebook, without having to register from my app (which should stay possible).

Once I retrieved user info from facebook, how do I store these in my database and more precisely, how can I retrieve these infos ? I read that you should get these with the unique id facebook provides. I have an issue here, if my php file ask user info with only an id, how can I prevent some bad guys retrieving everything they want about my users?

Anyone could do:

```
www.some_url.com/get_user_info_from_fb_id.php?user_id=whatever_id
```

and put hand on private data? Am I wrong?

Another question, when I store user data using facebook api, should I store them in a different mysql user table, say "fb_users", or should I store them in my already existing user table and add a field "fb_id"?